# Right-click a project in Eclipse triggers wsl.exe which triggers MFA prompt for Windows Authenticator

Tags: eclipse, windows-subsystem-for-linux, multi-factor-authentication

When I right-click a project in Eclipse, it seems it is running "wsl.exe" since I get a prompt for MFA and Windows Authenticator kicks in. I can authenticate without any issues, but not sure why this happens. I am 100% sure this is new, and it started just about a week ago.

I have:
Eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520

## Update:

I found out that if I start Eclipse as Admin, it won't prompt me with the MFA dialog.

[image]

Any idea how to troubleshoot this to avoid this MFA prompt? It is annoying and takes time.

Comment: Which of the downloads/install options of 2023-03 is that? Did you add anything to it?

Comment: It's downloaded about 2 years ago. I didn't do anything that stands out. I just remembered that this happened after in installed openssl for Windows. I think this is related.